# Positioning Cursor in a Text Editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a simple text editor, and I want to implement the functionality where the user can click on any written text and start editing it.

I have created a caret div, which represents the cursor, and I position it based on the clicked position. However, I'm facing an issue where if I click in the middle of a letter, the caret is being positioned there, but I want it to be shown after the letter.

To illustrate the problem, I have attached two screenshots:

what is happining
[image]

what i want
[image]

Red caret is basically a div whose top and left I am setting based on mouse click position.

In the desired behavior, the red caret div is positioned after the clicked letter.

I have tried to understand the logic used in existing text editors like Visual Studio Code, but the code is quite complex.

I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance on how to achieve the desired behavior.

I tried to understand how other code editors like vscode is generating caret position but there code is complex to understand

Comment: Can you post some code, to reproduce this ?

Comment: How is the editor implemented? Is it a canvas or textarea?

Comment: Have you heard of Monospace fonts?

Comment: I am using text area not canvas

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have created a stack blitz project, sharing the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ukcw5z?file=src%2FTextEditor%2FtextEditor.tsx).

Answer (score 0):

The Suggested Approach - For Caret Repositioning, Check if any string element is present on the clicked co-oridnates .IF no, render the caret.
If yes Adjust Caret Position to fall on shifted co-oridnates.

- Attach a ref to the div element in which the string is rendered, using the useRef hook.capture the click event  with listener.
- Retrieve the X and Y coordinates to handle click event.
- Use getBoundingClientRect()  to obtain its position and dimensions relative to the viewport.
- subtract the div's top and left positions from the click event's coordinates.
- Use the document.elementFromPoint(x, y) method to retrieve the DOM element at the specified X and Y coordinates.
- If the DOM element contains text content, you can extract the character at that position using the textContent property.

The below code use "HandleDivClick()" to get  Adjust Caret Position.
It is not complete, but you may get the idea.

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

function TextEditor() {
  const divRef = useRef(null);
  const [caretPosition, setCaretPosition] = useState(null);
  
    const handleTextClick = (event) => {
    const clickedPosition = getCaretPosition(event); 
    const adjustedPosition = adjustCaretPosition(clickedPosition);
    setCaretPosition(adjustedPosition);
   };

  const getCaretPosition = (event) => {
   
  };

  const adjustCaretPosition = (clickedPosition) => {
    // logic based on handleDivClick's text  content
  };

  const handleDivClick = (event) => {
    const { clientX, clientY } = event;

    const { top, left } = divRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    const offsetX = clientX - left;
    const offsetY = clientY - top;

    const element = document.elementFromPoint(offsetX, offsetY);

    if (element && element.textContent) {
      const character = element.textContent;
      console.log('Clicked character:', character);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div ref={divRef} onClick={handleDivClick}>
      Your Text Content
       {caretPosition && (
        <div
          className="caret"
          style={{ top: caretPosition.y, left: caretPosition.x }}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default TextEditor;
```

Comment: Thank you joydip007x but the above code is not giving the desired result, when I click at "C" of "Your Text Content" ," console. log('Clicked character:', character);" code line still prints "Clicked character: Your Text Content", I was expecting it to print "Clicked character: C"

Comment: I have created a stack blitz project, sharing the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ukcw5z?file=src%2FTextEditor%2FtextEditor.tsx).